# In react how to avoid avoid repetitive code for calling similar api’s

Tags: reactjs

I have 5 apis with the same input and output. For example, getApples(takes in storeId and returns a list of Fruit) and get bananas (takes in storeId and returns a list of Fruit).

I am wondering what is the best way to call this in react.
Should I create a separate component for each fruit. Create a mapping and pass in the fruit name as a key? I am trying to avoid repetitive code. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you referring to typescript types/models or actual components?

Comment: `const FruitList = ({ fruitType, storeId }) ` ?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid repetitive code when dealing with multiple APIs that have similar inputs and outputs in a React application, you can adopt a more dynamic approach to calling these APIs. You can try creating a **Generic API Utility Function**

Create a generic API utility function that can be customized with parameters, such as the fruit name or the specific endpoint. This function would take the storeId and a parameter that differentiates each API call (e.g., the fruit name) and returns the appropriate list of fruits.

```
// apiUtils.js

const getFruits = async (fruitName, storeId) => {
  const response = await fetch(`http://example.com/api/${fruitName}/${storeId}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```